# modalpopupextender set to multiple target control IDs?

Tags: c#, ajax

Is it possible to tie one modalpopupextender to multiple target controls (multiple buttons)?

Thanks
Behrouz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Answer, I will just add to it:

1. For me I had to change onclick to OnClientClick:

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="btn_contact2" runat="server" 
               OnClientClick="javascript:$find('popup1').show();return false;" 
               Text="Possibilites" />
   ```
2. You need to add a BehaviorID to the modalpopup:

   ```
   BehaviorID="popup1"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can specify multiple targets for the ModalPopupExtender.  But you can call it from other controls via JavaScript by adding something like this to their onclick handler:

```
<act:ModalPopupExtender id="mpePopup" runat="server" BehaviorID="bePopup" ... />
<asp:Button id="btnOther" runat="server" Text="Open Dialog" OnClientClick="$find('bePopup').show();return false;" />
```

The key is to provide a value for "BehaviorID" in the extender control.  This enables client-side access via the "$find(behaviorID)" method, from which you can ".show()" or ".hide()" the modal popup.

Comment: This page gives a more complete answer but it's basically the same: http://forums.asp.net/t/1155979.aspx/1